# How to spli XML-Like Tags in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, split

I need help. I'm reading a file (not XML file) in which a content is much like XML in form:

```
<xml> <details> 
<details><number>AB053091351</number><totalcontent>2</totalcontent></details>
<details><number>AB053091996</number><totalcontent>2</totalcontent></details>
<details><number>AB053092621</number><totalcontent>2</totalcontent></details>
<details><number>AB053093365</number><totalcontent>0</totalcontent></details>
</details> </xml>
```

I doing this:

```
$TRGFile <<-- filename of the content above.


    $result = Get-Content $TRGFile
    $pattern = '<policynumber>'
    $detailResult = ($result |Select-String -Pattern $pattern)
```

The result gave me this:

```
<details><number>AB053091351</number><totalcontent>2</totalcontent></details>
<details><number>AB053091996</number><totalcontent>2</totalcontent></details>
<details><number>AB053092621</number><totalcontent>2</totalcontent></details>
<details><number>AB053093365</number><totalcontent>0</totalcontent></details>
```

I need to loop on each line to get the value within "AB053091351" & "2". Take note that though this is XML in patter but it is plainly text.

Anyone knows how to extract the value within those tags? What Powershell function/cmdlet appropriate for this.?

he file is in .txt. I trid to convert the file as XML using this:

```
 Get-Content E:\file.txt | Export-CliXML E:\file.xml
```

In order for me to do the code just like the one you have provided. but the XML file generated is different:

```
<Obj RefId="5">
  <S><details><number>053091351</number><contentpages>2</contentpages></details></S> 
</Obj>
```

In which

```
<details><number>053091351</number><contentpages>2</contentpages></details>

was referred as string & not as tag.
```

Comment: The sample data and your code don't fit. Where do you get that `$pattern = '<policynumber>'` from?

Comment: How does this format differ from XML?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you want to do with that data (and still wondering where there is a difference to XML and why you can't handle the file as XML), but this should get you started:

```
foreach ($elem in $detailResult){write-host (([xml]$elem).details.number+" "+([xml]$elem).details.totalcontent)}
```